# How to remove ?cat=id in url magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: php, magento, url, cat, catalog

I can't remove ?cat=... in url:
https://2been.com/beauty/makeup?cat=1198
I want change it to:
domain/beauty/makeup/catname.html
or
domain/catname.html
Help me to change it. Thank so much !

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable friendly URL's, Go to `System > Configuration > Web` and then enable `use web server rewrites`. Also, a guide with screenshots here: [link](http://magentohostsolution.com/enable-search-engine-friendly-urls-magento/)

Comment: Please don't just link to a source, if that site every goes down then the answer is useless should anyone have the same problem.

Comment: Try to reindex the catalog URL. The option is in `System > Index Management` and select `Catalog Url Rewrites` to reindex

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to pass parameter in Array like below when you set category url

```
$url=Mage::getUrl("url", array('param_name'=>$paramValue));
```

hope this help you